# Jackson can't deserialize object despite having public setters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson

I have entity:

**DummyEntity.java**

```
package com.example.demo.DummyObject;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * An entity containing analyzed data
 *
 * @author Thorvas
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="DUMMY_ENTITY")
public class DummyEntity {

    public DummyEntity() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, Integer> population;

    @Column(name = "estimation")
    private int estimation;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonProperty("last_updated")
    private Date lastUpdated;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(Map<String, Integer> population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public int getEstimation() {
        return estimation;
    }

    public void setEstimation(int estimation) {
        this.estimation = estimation;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I post following data on my POST Endpoint:

```
{
  "name": "Powiat ząbkowicki",
  "population": {
    "2013": 67875,
    "2014": 67458,
    "2015": 66971,
    "2016": 66527,
    "2017": 66009,
    "2018": 65428,
    "2019": 64802,
    "2020": 62561,
    "2021": 61846,
    "2022": 61087
  },
  "estimation": 0,
  "last_updated": "2023-06-09"
}
```

And when I post it, I get an error:

```
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"name": "Powiat ząbkowicki", "population": {"2013": 67875, "2014": 67458, "2015": 66971, "2016": 66527, "2017": 66009, "2018": 65428, "2019": 64802, "2020": 62561, "2021": 61846, "2022": 61087}, "estimation": 0, "last_updated": "2023-06-09"}')]
```

Why? All my setters and getters are public. For some reason Jackson can't deserialize my object properly and wants constructor with String value. When I add this, the problem is solved:

```
public DummyEntity(String json) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DummyEntity dummyEntity = objectMapper.readValue(json, DummyEntity.class);
        this.name = dummyEntity.name;
        this.population = dummyEntity.population;
        this.estimation = dummyEntity.estimation;
        this.lastUpdated = dummyEntity.lastUpdated;
    }
```

But why we need this constructor? Can't Jackson do it itself?

Comment: Check if your input String is a valid json. Such error could occur if you pass a String like \"\"

Comment: But when I add constructor which takes ```json``` as String parameter and literally applies every value from deserialized ```json``` to ```this``` then I suppose that sent json is valid

Comment: First of all consider making population as a list. Currently it doesn’t look as a good practice. Are you going to change the contract every year?

Comment: For testing try to print your input, verify that no escape character `\` is being added at the start of the json string

Comment: @ValeriiSloboda My friend sends me data from his python data-analysis module. He has to send me dictionary field (which is ```"population"```) so I map it to Map<String, Integer>. I want to know why I need to declare constructor with String argument if we have public setters. With this constructor everything works fine. But why we need it?

Answer (score 0):

> no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from
> String value ('{"name": "Powiat ząbkowicki",....

The error message explains your application received a `String` object containing the json you would convert to your `DummyEntity` object instead of the json representation of the `DummyEntity` object; you have to convert the string value to a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) node and read its associated value as a valid `String` representation with the [`JsonNode#asText`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText--) method:

```
@Data
public class DummyEntity {
    private String name;
}

// deserializing json "{\"name\": \"Powiat ząbkowicki\"}"
String content = mapper.readTree(json).asText();
DummyEntity dummyEntity = mapper.readValue(content, DummyEntity.class);
//ok, it prints DummyEntity(name=Powiat ząbkowicki)
System.out.println(dummyEntity);
```